# Does using a LINQ statement in a foreach re-evaluate the statement on each iteration

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

So what I am wondering is whether using a `LINQ where` clause in my `foreach` loop means that on each iteration it will re-evaluate my `LINQ where` clause. For example:

```
var MyId = 1;
foreach (var thing in ListOfThings.Where(x => x.ID == MyId))
{ 
  //do Something
}
```

or is it better to write:

```
var MyId = 1;

var myList = ListOfThings.Where(x => x.ID == MyId);
foreach (var thing in myList)
{ 
  //do Something
}
```

or are they both work in exactly the same way?

Comment: the last question: yes

Comment: this same :-) any way `Where` return iterator, so executed only once

Comment: take a IL disassembler and disassemble both codes, then you will see if there is a difference

Comment: @IssaJaber The IL for both can never be the same .. his question is whether they perform the same function ... which they do.

Comment: You can test it by making the `Where` clause call a function (e.g. `Where(x => TestFunc(x))` and in the test function, write to your debug/console. You will see it only runs on the first iteration.

Comment: @DavidG Good Idea, although I must add that `TestFunc` will execute for each item in your list therefore the real test is that the number of times `TestFunc` executes is the same as `List.Count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample should give you all the answers you seek:

### Code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create sequence of integers from 0 to 10
        var sequence = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(p => 
        { 
            // In each 'where' clause, print the current item.
            // This shows us when the clause is executed
            Console.WriteLine(p); 

            // Make sure every value is selected
            return true;
        });

        foreach(var item in sequence)
        {
            // Print a marker to show us when the loop body is executing.
            // This helps us see if the 'where' clauses are evaluated 
            // before the loop starts or during the loop
            Console.WriteLine("Loop body exectuting.");
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
0
Loop body exectuting.
1
Loop body exectuting.
2
Loop body exectuting.
3
Loop body exectuting.
4
Loop body exectuting.
5
Loop body exectuting.
6
Loop body exectuting.
7
Loop body exectuting.
8
Loop body exectuting.
9
Loop body exectuting.
```

### Conclusion

The `Where` clause is evaluated once, for the current element, at the start of each loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

`foreach (var thing in myExpression)` calls `myExpression.GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext`s until it returns false.  So your two snippets are the same.

(Incidentally, `GetEnumerator` is a method on `IEnumerable`, but `myExpression` doesn't have to be an `IEnumerable`; just a thing with a `GetEnumerator` method).

Answer (score 0):

So from the comments I have worked out that the `foreach` loop does not re-evaluate my `LINQ where` on each iteration.

From [MSDN Enumerable.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.90).aspx) I can see that this method returns an `IEnumerable`

> Return Value Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable An
>   IEnumerable that contains elements from the input sequence that
>   satisfy the condition.

That is then iterated over in the `foreach` loop